# Is there any way to add custom command processor to xmpp char rooms for voting?

Tags: xmpp, bots, openfire, messenger

I'm very new to xmpp and jabber services.

I try to add voting ability to jabber chat rooms. What is the best way to do it?

I know, there are some bots written for jabber. 
I have openfire server. I think, bot can be added to every chat room, created on server, but what is the way to store voting results, for example.

Case:

1. Chat room is created
2. Users are added
3. Bot is added to room
4. Bot reads messages and when it gets

   > /voting firtree:'FirTree decoration' 1:'red balls' 2:'green balls'
5. Voting is created
6. User sends

   > '/vote firtree:1'

   and his vote goes to 1st variant of firtree voting.

Comment: Hello, sadfuzzy ! Just want know if you have some progress on it. Will be glad for some sharing. In case of success.

Comment: found this as an example solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmpp-command-bot